# Touch Events touchesCancelled and touchesEnded

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, touch-event, tap, touchescancelled

I have a project that I started out using a tap gesture recognizer for. I realized I didn't have enough control with the tap gesture recognizer, so I've started coding with using my viewcontroller as a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Just to make sure I was on the right track, I added methods for `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled`. The methods are empty except for `NSLog` calls so I can tell what is being fired when I try different things.

Things worked as expected except that I was getting a bunch of calls to touchesCancelled. I assume this is because of the tap gesture recognizer I still have in place. I'm not ready to remove the tap gesture recognizer, so I just wanted to confirm that this is what would happen if a gesture I used was actually a tap.

The documentation says:

> This method is invoked when the Cocoa Touch framework receives a
>   system interruption requiring cancellation of the touch event; for
>   this, it generates a `UITouch` object with a phase of
>   `UITouchPhaseCancel`. The interruption is something that might cause the
>   application to be no longer active or the view to be removed from the
>   window When an object receives a `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` message
>   it should clean up any state information that was established in its
>   `touchesBegan:withEvent:` implementation.

But I suspect my scenario just outlined is just as likely. Am I correct?

Comment: You can implement `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` without the use of a gesture recognizer. Remove the recognizer and these methods should still be called.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think what I'll do is this: Use locationInView in touchesBegan to flag the view I intend to move. In touchesMoved, I use that tag, comparing to previousLocationInView to match the touch with the view to be moved. Meanwhile, the tag is updated with the new locationInView. I continue this in touchesEnded/touchesCancelled, the last step. If in touchesEnded, I move the view. If in touchesCancelled, I clean up instead (remove the tag).